# WSO2 initial setup error while running apim

Tags: windows, wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

I followed the documentation here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/api-manager-quick-start-guide/

I have jdk17 installed on Windows 11 and followed the installation steps, however in the bin directory running the below command to start the wso2 server gives errors

api-manager.bat --run

```html
ERROR - JMXServerManager Could not create the RMI local registry
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:346) ~[?:?]
```

Here is how the log starts -
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\WSO2\wso2am-4.2.0\bin..

Attaching full log. The ask is to setup WSO2 locally and use api management with keycloak, I also have keycloak installed, but trying to get wso2 to run is resulting in these errors.

Checked for ports in use and killed related processes, restarting api-manager.bat did not help.

Please let me know if any alternative exists to solution this issue.

Thanks!

more logs -

```html
[2023-07-11 11:05:47,273] ERROR - JMXServerManager Could not create the RMI local registry java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:346)
~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:415) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:235)
~[?:?] at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:223) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.
<init>(RegistryImpl.java:208) ~[?:?] at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203) ~[?:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager.startJMXService(JMXServerManager.java:94) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:205)
  ~[?:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:309) ~[?:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:118)
  ~[org.wso2.carbon.tenant.throttling.agent_4.9.20.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:96) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tenant.throttling.agent_4.9.20.jar:?] at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
  Method) ~[?:?] at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
  ~[?:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
  ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
  ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
  ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529)
  ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
  ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
  ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?] at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[?:?] at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:544) ~[?:?] at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643) ~[?:?] at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:388)
  ~[?:?] at java.net.ServerSocket.
  <init>(ServerSocket.java:274) ~[?:?] at java.net.ServerSocket.
    <init>(ServerSocket.java:167) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:673) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
      ~[?:?] ... 49 more [2023-07-11 11:05:52,311] ERROR - JMXServerManager Could not initialize RMI server java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException:
      non-JRMP server at remote endpoint] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:834) ~[?:?] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:481) ~[?:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager.startJMXService(JMXServerManager.java:134)
      ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:205) ~[?:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:309)
      ~[?:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tenant.throttling.agent_4.9.20.jar:?]
      at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:96) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tenant.throttling.agent_4.9.20.jar:?] at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
      Method) ~[?:?] at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
      ~[?:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
      ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
      ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
      ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) ~[org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529)
      ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
      ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.8.1.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
      ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?] Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:163)
      ~[?:?] at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:243) ~[?:?] at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.bind(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:719) ~[?:?] at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:417)
      ~[?:?] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:693) ~[?:?] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:476) ~[?:?] ... 42 more Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP
      server at remote endpoint at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:252) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:204) ~[?:?] at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:344) ~[?:?]
      at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:65) ~[?:?] at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:157) ~[?:?] at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:243) ~[?:?]
      at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.bind(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:719) ~[?:?] at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:417) ~[?:?] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:693)
      ~[?:?] at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:476) ~[?:?] ... 42 more [2023-07-11 11:05:54,518] INFO - EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker carbon.super_sub_AsyncWHSilver.siddhiql is deleted from
      the file system [2023-07-11 11:05:54,519] INFO - EventProcessorDeployer Execution Plan was undeployed successfully : carbon.super_sub_AsyncWHSilver.siddhiql
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, despite these running errors, I noticed that the server was already up and running.

Their error log was quite verbose so the server startup got lost in between -

https://localhost:9443/carbon/ I am able to access this now.
Thanks